# Android - Can't make focused TableRow highlighted

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I wish my table rows highlight when i touch it and return to its default color right after but i can't understand why nothing happens. May be it is just a missing thing into xml files or its impossible but there is my code anyway :

**table_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:state_activated="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hover_state" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/default_state" />  
</selector>
```

(my states files are just shapes with colors.)

**detail_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableValues"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/table_selector" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dataSize" />

    <View style="@style/VDivider" />

                 [...]
```

**detail_table.xml**

```
                 [...]

 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/detailTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true" >
            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Hope that someone will bring me light. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

check below code 
If you want to use the stock on click highlight like you get with a generic ListView, you want to set the background of each row to be      android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"

Here is an example:

```
<TableLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="0">
<TableRow
 android:id="@+id/first_row"
 android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" >
... row content ...
```

Then in code,

```
TableRow firstRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.first_row);
firstRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO: do your logic here

    }   
}
```

And you should get a highlight-able row just like in a ListView...

Comment: It is not what i was looking for. I just want my tablerows change color when i hover/press it, no particular behaviour on touch but just highlight when selected or just hovered

Comment: check if this helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080900/listview-normal-and-hover-background-style-in-android

Comment: I have already my lists working this way but i want the same process with my TableLayout.