# How to highlight the grid view item on select?

Tags: android

I am creating a Grid view layout with image and text.I want multi-select of item which is working fine but i want to highlight the grid items which is selected.

Here is my code:

```
public class FragMent1 extends Fragment{

        BaseAdapter MyAdapter;
    private Context mContext;

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public FragMent1(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.g, null);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview,null);
        final GridView listView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
        listView.setAdapter(new Adapter());
        //listView.setSelection(1);
        listView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mode.setTitle("Select Items");
                mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int selectCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
                switch (selectCount) {
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");

                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");

                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                    long id, boolean checked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                int selectCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
                switch (selectCount) {
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                    break;
                }

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View myView = convertView;

            ImageView image;
            if (convertView == null) {
                image = new ImageView(FragMent1.this.getActivity());
                image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);



                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);           
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items_ontap, null);


                // Add The Image!!!           
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image_OnTap);
                iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


                // Add The Text!!!
                TextView tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text_onTap);
                tv.setText(names[position] );






            }
            return myView;
        }

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car
        };

        private String[] names={"ab","cd","ef","gh","ij","kl","mn"};


    }
}
```

what should i add to the code for highlighting the grid item which will be selected.

Please suggest me some way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you inflate the view in the adapter, you can set a Style defined in Styles.xml file.

Comment: will u expalin me.I didnt get you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080900/listview-normal-and-hover-background-style-in-android

Comment: I also want to know that in my above code there is MultiChoiceModeListener() method which select the grid item on long tap but i need on click it should be selected.Will u tell me any way to remove long tap in my above code.So,I can fulfill my requirement.

Comment: why ´GridView´ is called listview? so confusing..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use selector to highlight item

In drawable folder create a xml file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

and set listSelector of your gridview like

android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

Comment: ok its working,but I want to hold that highlighted item when i select some other item also.Means whatever item is get selected it should be highlighted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395782/custom-adapter-selected-item-background/19395952#19395952

Comment: It not works in my app, Could you help to look at my post? thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125358/gridview-listselector-does-not-work-as-expected

Comment: If I changed the selector.xml to below. it will work.Why ?
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"  />
</selector> 
I am using emulator with android 4.4.2

Answer (score 10):

1. create ImageAdapter Class
2. add this parameter to your class
        `private int selectedPosition = -1`
3. add this method to your ImageAdapter Class

   ```
   public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
       selectedPosition = position;
   }
   ```
4. add to the end of your getView method of ImageAdapter Class these lines

   ```
   if (position == selectedPosition) {
           gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
       } else {
           gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       }
   ```
5. in your activity(or fragment) create object from ImageAdapter class
6. then just add these lines to test

   ```
   GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
   gridView.setAdapter(adapterImage);
   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                               int position, long id) {
           adapterImage.setSelectedPosition(position);
           adapterImage.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

if your grid view is inside a Relative layout you can set touch listener there to highlight the selected item by using a custom draw-able(here i use a nine patch image to specify the selection)

```
private RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener touchListener = new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(touchEnabled==false)
                return false;
            try {
                if (oldView != null) {
                    oldView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
                }
                setSelection(((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).pos);
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_pressed);
                oldView = v;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

or you can use selector as well

In drawable folder create a xml file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

and set listSelector of your gridview like

android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with `setTag` on `childItems`
this is my sample code

```
 yourGridView.setOnItemClickListener((parent1, view, position1, id1) -> {

            if (view.getTag()!=null && view.getTag().equals("Examplename")){
                view.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);
                view.setTag("");
            }else{

                view.setTag("Examplename");
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                int Nums=gridListItems.getChildCount();
                for (int i=0;  i<=Nums-1; i++ ){
                    if (i!=position1){
                     View child=   gridListItems.getChildAt(i);
                    child.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```