# Listview and row selector not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm puzzled with this. I am searching for over 2 hours and cannot understand what is happening.

I have a Listview that I want the items (rows) to be selectable.
To achieve this, I have a selector that I set as a background to my row layout.

The ListView is defined this way in the fragment.xml layout file:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_friends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />
```

The selector (**bg_row_contact.xml**) is this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

My row layout (**row_contact.xml**) is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_row_contact"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_lst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription_pic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have a custom adapter, in which I do this to mark an item as selected when the user clicks on the row, **which works perfect**:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // View from recycle
        View row = convertView;

        // Handle inflation and make sure not to re-use a header view
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);
            row.setTag(position);

            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                  
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
                }
            });
        }

        boolean condition = (position==3);

        row.setSelected(condition);
    }
```

My problem now is that I want to obviously maintain the selection state when the listview is scrolled. So I have a condition which I check against and set the row to selected or not based on this, as you can see in the

```
row.setSelected(boolean condition);
```

***The problem is that although the condition is true for some rows, the row's background selector is not working and the row is not highlighed.***

I have tried everything, but cannot find what the bleep is going on here.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `row.setSelected(boolean condition);` are you passing argument along with the datatype? It should be something like this `boolean condition; ..... row.setSelected(condition); `

Comment: This was just for explaining what I do. condition is a boolean defined based on a condition. It's either `true` or `false`

Comment: How do you make this 'condition' variable?

Comment: It seems too many people focus wrongly on the condition boolean. I can hard-code it to true, which should normally select all rows and highlight them all, but it doesn't select any row. Just to avoid confusion I have changed the code a bit, although this is a sample

Comment: I remember that I had a similar issue once, but the only thing I recall is that I had to swap the order of the listener and setting the selection. Although it was with a checkedStateChangeListener. I really don't know if it will help, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Try setting ListView choice mode to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` . `yourListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`

Comment: I already tried this, but if you see I'm not selecting the listview items with any way, just on the row click listener, I set the view as selected.

Comment: @Lefteris : take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395782/custom-adapter-selected-item-background/19395952#19395952

Comment: Unfortunately the `activatedBackgroundIndicator` is an API Level 11 attribute and we are targeting 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around a little and I think I found a solution to your problem. This one works with `list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

You can get the selected items via `list.getCheckedItemPositions()`. The only weird thing about it is, that in your selector you have to use `android:state_activated`instead of `android:state_checked`.

Activity code:

```
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // dummy values
    final String[] values = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
            "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
            "t", "u", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row_contact, values){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // View from recycle
            View row = convertView;

            // Handle inflation and make sure not to re-use a header view
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);
                row.setTag(position);

            }
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_title)).setText(values[position]);
            return row;
        }

    };
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

The selector (bg_row_contact.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and to select an row, I will use `row.setChecked(true)` ?

Comment: Nope, actually this was the whole code I used. The list apparently handles the checked items once you set `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`

Comment: Do you set the selector to the listview it self as an attribute?

Comment: No, I used your row_contact.xml where the selector is the background of the LinearLayout.

Comment: I actually got it working only by selecting the item my self with `mListView.setItemChecked(position, true);` but it finally works!