# A color of the last selected ListView item

Tags: android, listview, colors, android-custom-view

How to assign a color to the selected item of `ListView`? I read 
[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and downloaded the sample. They use `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`. When I select an item, its color *keeps being* blue. When I select a previously selected item, its color slightly changes.

The min. API I need is 10.

Comment: Show some code, let us see what you've done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395782/custom-adapter-selected-item-background/19395952#19395952

Comment: I've used custom adapter for this purpose. Other way is to use View that implements Checkable interface and switch ListView into selection mode.

Comment: @kaushik, `android:state_activated` was introduced in API level 11. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html The min. API level I need is **10**

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev :sorry i missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two ways:

**1)** Using `checkBox` by creating an item for the `ListView` and pass it through the `adapter` and the `checkBox` will handle the check and uncheck operations automatically.

**2)** Using the `adapter` by creating an `integer` value to hold the position of the selected item and check for it in the method `getView()` to draw it with different color

**adapter.class:**

```
    private static int selectedItemPosition = -1;

    public static void setSelectedITem(int i){
       selectedItemPosition = i;
    }

    public static void getSelectedITem(){
       return i;
    }

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position == selectedItemPosition){
                //Highlight your item or ViewHolder
                textView.setBackgroungColor(R.color.gray);
        //Complete the actions
    return view;
}
```

and from your `activity` or `fragment` set the position as following

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
       adapter.setSelectedITem(position);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps