# Android - Can I override simple_list_item_1 colors programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml

**EDIT: I've decided to go ahead and use a custom xml with a small change to get selection colors working.** This doesn't completely solve my issue but I don't want to spend more time on it right now. Posting my current xml below in case it helps someone, and marking correct answer since it helped me pretty much achieve what i was going for in the first place. I ended up not needing to point to another xml if I use `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
```

I've made a `GridView` wrapped in a `Dialog` with an `ArrayAdapter`.

I wanted to have some kind of border between the cells (1dp white or black). The only way I was capable of accomplishing this was to write a custom xml and use it instead of simple_list_item_1, which would be fine, except that seems to break the item highlighting on select and such, and I can't seem to match the default look of it with my custom xml.

The question: **Could I possibly just locate and override the color scheme of the built in xml?**

I made a small attempt in the code below, but unsurprisingly I get a null pointer exception. Most of the searching just turned up suggestions for a custom xml, but it seems odd to do all that for a quick font color and font background color change.

I'll throw in my xmls just in case.
Working with a minimum API 11 if it matters.

Thanks guys,

Mike

-Java Snippet-

```
...

public void gridDialog(View v) {

    String[] letters = new String[] { 
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.grid_pop);

    GridView mGrid = (GridView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.fret_grid);    

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, letters);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_item, letters);
    mGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

            // Do Stuff
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
...
```

-my_item.xml-

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

-grid_pop.xml-

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fret_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:columnWidth="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

and your item's will have the default selection behavior with the custom list item XML (a theory, haven't tested).

EDIT: Try this to make the list item light up when you tap it like the simple_list_item_1:

In the list item:

```
android:background="@drawable/clickable"
```

In drawable folder add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />      
</selector>
```

Comment: I had that in place but had to pull it because eclipse gives me a "minimum API 14 required" type error

Comment: oh gosh, i thought it wouldn't build but now i see that it will let me, one second. edit: "project contains errors, fix before running"

Comment: Ok try this post if that edit doesn't work, I'm not able to test this stuff myself atm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292369/how-to-highlight-the-grid-view-item-on-select

Comment: Ok. that gave me a selection highlighter again, only it's not matching the theme. the rest of the app has a light blue selection (I'm using Theme.Holo.Light) and this dialog now has orange. thanks so far. Edit: sry I didn't refresh page, I meant to say that your code gave me what I have so far

Comment: I think I can poke my way through now that you got selection back for me, and I'll take a look at that post too. one last question though. Since I've got drawable folders for all the dpi buckets would i need to put that xml in each one or could i make another folder, say @myfolder/clickable?

Comment: just one drawable folder is fine, you can use /drawable since it's common