# Unable to display listview style in android Emulator

Tags: android, android-listview, android-emulator

Below is the code :

I have written code same like this:

[listview normal and hover background style in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080900/listview-normal-and-hover-background-style-in-android)

But I am getting the view in SDK as :
like colors and divider

But this output i am not getting on Emulator

The output of the Emulator is :
I am not getting any color,or divider in emulator

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstpass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/listbackimage"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

**gradient_bg.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#e8eef4"
        android:centerColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:endColor="#d3dfe8"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#b7ccdd" />
    <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="6dp" android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <margin android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**gradient_bg_hover.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffe181"
        android:centerColor="#f5cd4a"
        android:endColor="#e8c34e"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e3b52c" />

    <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="6dp" android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <margin android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Waiting for your valuable answers..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put your code and what issue you have?

Comment: I am unable to post image here as i have <10 reputation.. In emulator I am only getting white background but not colored background

Comment: put your image somewhere and give the link, plus your code, how you used that? XMLs, put something you done personally so that we figure out the issue. The link you referring is itself a question so that's possibility not to be correct as you needed.

Comment: @Saqib.. plz go through my updated question

Comment: where is your gradient_bg_hover.xml?

Comment: let me check your xml

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used

**main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstpass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**gradient_bg.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#e8eef4"
        android:centerColor="#fdfdfd"
        android:endColor="#d3dfe8"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#b7ccdd" />
    <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="6dp" android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <margin android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**gradient_bg_hover.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffe181"
        android:centerColor="#f5cd4a"
        android:endColor="#e8c34e"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e3b52c" />

    <padding android:left="6dp" android:top="6dp" android:right="6dp"
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <margin android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp" android:right="15dp"
        android:bottom="15dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

and this is what I get as output, is that what you needed?

**Normal View**

[image: Normal ListView]

**Hover View**

[image: Hover ListView]

Comment: But I am not getting any divider or white block as you got in Emulator ? Anything I need to set in manifest or any other settings i need to make ?